# Iterate over explicitly given folders containing spaces

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have read a dozen threads and am still unable to solve this task (shame on me). My batch file

```
for %%x in ( 
    "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%"
    "%PROGRAMFILES%"
    ) do (
        echo x=%%x
        )
    )
```

was supposed to output

```
 x=C:\Program Files (x86)
 x=C:\Program Files
```

but it outputs

```
 x="C:\Program Files (x86)"
 x="C:\Program Files"
```

I understand why it does, but am unable to modify the for-loop accordingly.

My intention is to have a nested loop iterating over explicitly given folders ("..." being placeholders for more folder names):

```
for %%x in ( 
    %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%
    %PROGRAMFILES%
    ...
    ) do (
        for %%y in ( ... ) do (
            if exist %%x\%%y (
                echo yep
            )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    echo x=%%~x
```

`~` removes enclosing quotes (in the correct context)

so in the second part,

```
        if exist "%%~x\%%~y" (
```

(need to re-insert the quotes because the target filename contains spaces)